# Как определить следующий идентификатор (ID), который будет присвоен?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, у меня есть база:

```
|ID | Name | Count|
| 1 | val1 |  3   |
......
| 7 | val7 |  3   |
| 8 | val8 |  3   |
| 9 | val9 |  3   |
```

Если удалю последний товар (9) и добавлю другой товар, то ID будет 10.
Как мне заранее определить какой ID будет присвоен следующему товару?

Comment: базу указывайте, mysql/sqlite/postgres/mssql/firebird  и т.д.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('Моя таблица') + 1;  
GO
```

Функция возвращает последнее выданное значение для поля IDENTITY, прибавив единицу - получите следующее значение.

Если вы собираетесь что-то с ним делать потом, не рекомендую пользоваться именно таким способом, лучше после вставки воспользоваться одной из функций SCOPE_IDENTITY или @@IDENTITY, если вы можете гарантировать, что вставлена была одна строка, либо воспользоваться выражением OUTPUT, чтобы поместить все вставленные значения во временную таблицу и впоследствии их обработать.

Comment: можно так думать, пока в таблице, из которой ничего не удалялось не увидишь последовательности `1,2,3, 1001`. в рамках одной сессии такого не будет, но в целом это не так.

Comment: @teran, судя по классическому разрыву в 1000, вы, по всей видимости, столкнулись с кэшированием значений IDENTITY. Начиная, кажется, с версии SQL Server 2012 новые значения IDENTITY кэшируются в памяти по 1000 штук, и выдаются новым записям из памяти. Если сервер перезагружается, кэш исчезает, и SQL Server закэширует следующие 1000 записей, и начнет выдавать идентификаторы из них.
В целом, IDENTITY не гарантирует непрерывности, он гарантирует только неповторяемость (не будет дублирующихся значений) и монотонное возрастание (следующее выданное значение будет больше предыдущего).

Comment: дак вот о том и речь, что `+1` в целом - не ответ.

Comment: @teran, именно поэтому я и сделал оговорку, что на такое значение полагаться нельзя, и нужно пользоваться другими способами.